# BackboneJS + HandlebarsJS - how to add image based on css

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a backbone application, where I want to display the "home"-link as an icon. I'm using HandlebarsJS so I dont really know how to achieve this.

I have in mind to use this:

```
<span class="font-entypo icon-home"></span>
```

and then in my CSS I would do:

```
span.font-entypo.icon-home:before{content:'\2302'};
```

so basically my menu would look like this:

```
<a href="home"><span class="font-entypo icon-home"></span></a>
<a href="page1">page1</a>
<a href="page2">page2</a>
<a href="page3">page3</a> ....
```

Now my HTML with HandlebarsJS is this:

```
<a href="{{href}}">{{text}}</a>
```

and my Backbone View is alike for each menuitem:

```
this.insertView(new ItemView({
    model: new Navigation.ItemModel({
    href: '#page1',
    text: 'page1',
    triggers: 'page1',
    route: this.route
    })
}));
```

Does anyone have an idea? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple solution is to add a class to your template

```
<a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{text}}</a>
```

and on your model, add the property `class : 'font-entypo icon-home'`